# Unable to open /etc/smbldap-tools/smbldap.conf for reading?

Tags: 16.04, server, samba, ldap

Following [the server guide to setup Samba authentication with OpenLDAP](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-ldap.html)

All seems to go well until `Adding Samba LDAP objects` when running this command:

```
sudo smbldap-populate
```

I get this error:

```
Unable to open /etc/smbldap-tools/smbldap.conf for reading !  
Compilation failed in require at /usr/sbin/smbldap-populate line 30.  
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/sbin/smbldap-populate line 30.
```

I've checked and in deed the folder `/etc/smbldap-tools` exists, but is empty, missing the required `smbldap.conf`

I've tried:

```
sudo apt purge smbldap-tools
```

Which removes the directory, but when I reinstall:

```
sudo apt install smbldap-tools
```

It just creates an empty folder again. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

If you read the directions *very* closely, it says:

> The package comes with a configuration helper script, smbldap-config.pl, that will ask questions.

So with a little guesswork, the missing step is to run:

```
sudo smbldap-config
```

which will run through an interactive script that will generate both:

```
/etc/smbldap-tools/smbldap.conf
/etc/smbldap-tools/smbldap_bind.conf
```

Comment: The instructions are being fixed and made more clear. Please see https://bugs.launchpad.net/serverguide/+bug/1579209

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the file was omitted by whoever packaged it. The corresponding Fedora package has it; you could grab it and put in place. Or you could grab a copy [from the source code here](http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/smbldap-tools/trunk/smbldap.conf?revision=176&view=markup).